# passport.js - getting user ID to then query mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

very new to passport.js so please forgive me.

Everything is working perfectly and I'm able to redirect the user once logged in and then display there username + a welcome message.

What I'm stuck with though is, how can I get the ID from req.user so I can then do a db.collections.find and display data from the database that has been inserted with that users ID? For example here is my get which redirects the user to index and shows there username

```
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.render('index', { user : req.user });
    console.log(req.user._id);

  });
```

But I can't get the .ID to show? / Am I even doing this in the right place? The console.log just crashed as ID is undefined, yet it is available in the req.user object when console.log'd?

Comment: Look up npm module passport-local and passport-local-mongoose. They might help you understand e what passport does and also solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just putting `req.user.id`

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {     
    console.log(req.user.id);
});
```

This will work once the user is logged into the system with passport

Comment: okay thanks, do you know if theres any way to check if is not equal to undefined? I'm getting a crash error saying "cannot read property id of undefined. I've tried doing typeof id !=== undefined but it still crashes edit: added if (req.user) and it worked. THANKS!